# I'm looking for the way to handle pre & post processing of Controller in Spring Boot + thymeleaf

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have been looking for the way to handle pre & post processing of controller.

I want to add  a procedure for every request & response.
For example:
Checking every requested header or adding hidden field include hash code in every form tags we response.

If there is sample, or any idea,give me please.

Comment: Read about Aspect Oriented Programming (AOP) in Spring documentation.

Comment: Maybe implement a custom Filter where you get HttpRequest and/or HttpResponse Objects and modify them.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for advice.

I was able to find the result from this page.

http://www.concretepage.com/spring/spring-mvc/spring-handlerinterceptor-annotation-example-webmvcconfigureradapter

```
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    super.addInterceptors(registry);
    registry.addInterceptor(new ControllerHandler());

    TransactionInterceptor transactionInterceptor = new TransactionInterceptor();
}
}

public class ControllerHandler implements HandlerInterceptor  {
@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler)
    throws Exception {
    System.out.println("---Before Method Execution---");
    return true;
}
@Override
public void postHandle( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("---method executed---");
}
@Override
public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        Object handler, Exception ex) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("---Request Completed---");
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found another way to do,using @ControllerAdvice.
This annotaion seems to focus Error Handling.

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ControllerAdvice.html1

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionControllerAdvice {

 @InitBinder
 public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    System.out.println("controller advice: init binder");
}


@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
public String exception(Exception e) {
    System.out.println("controller advice: exception Handler");
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    return "error";
}

@ModelAttribute
public void modelAttribute(){
    System.out.println("controller advice:model Attribute");
}
}
```